# can we count no of established TCP connection in a complete day (say for Day-1) on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, sockets, tcp

is there any Linux hack command to give Total No of Established TCP connections made up on a particular port for a complete day (Let say i want to count total no of TCP Connections on a port for current_day-1).
i am able to find out Established Tcp connections for an instant using

`netstat -an | grep -c 3306`

can anybody help me regarding this.

Comment: look http://serverfault.com/questions/581354/how-can-i-find-the-total-number-of-tcp-connections-for-a-given-port-and-period-o

Comment: @Jayesh i have already following the same but i am working on live server any other alternative or with same `netstat`

Answer (score 0):

Try using iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j LOG and log level verbosity options . and in your log file you will see time, date and ip and other informations